# How to use Xerces while generating sources from XSD 1.1 with maven

Tags: maven, xsd, xerces

I have a XSD file with assertion tags. I have read that Xerces supports a XML Schema 1.1 draft with these tags.

How can I use an actual Xerces version, instead of the standard Java implementation, in my maven build.

Answer (score 0):

An old way to use the Xerces version was adding those parameters. I do not know if it could still work.

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParser=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl
```

Comment: If I give it to maven, it seems to replace it for the maven process, but not for the xjc plugin.