# Is there any way to generate java source from xsd1.1?

Tags: java, code-generation, xsd-1.1

I want to generate the java source (classes) which represent the XML elements in the XSD1.1 file to be able to serialize / deserialize incomming XML files. With xsd1.0 it works perfectly with the in java included tool xjc but I fail generating the classes with an XSD1.1 file.

I have already tried several tools

- xjc (jdk8)
- apache cxf
- some maven plugins

Always trying also to put the latest xerces-j in the classpath "2.12.0".

As far as I could figure out xerces has no functionality like "xjc" or "xsd2java".

I also tried this one: [How to use Xerces while generating sources from XSD 1.1 with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816544/how-to-use-xerces-while-generating-sources-from-xsd-1-1-with-maven/14817062#14817062)

And to code it my own - to have more influence on the classpath and implementation - like its explained a bit here:
[How do I add an xjc plugin programmatically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355627/how-do-i-add-an-xjc-plugin-programmatically-at-runtime)

Thanks

Comment: Java source *for what*?  I mean, the most likely thing is probably source for one or more classes representing documents conforming to the XSD, or elements declared within, or both.  But even then, the question of *for what purpose?* is essential in determining how such classes should be formed.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I have updated my post

Comment: Sorry, but what problems are you have? It looks like my 1.1 scheme compiled normally by xjc. Could you provide example of `xsd` file, command you are run and erros you get